# sorting a list of class instances by attribut ip

Tags: python, list, sorting, ip

I'm a little lost. I want to sort a list, that has the format of :

```
[instance_of_myClass, instance_of_myClass, instance_of_myClass...]
```

`init` of `myClass` looks like this:

```
def __init__(self):
   self.ip = ""
   self.hostname = ""
   self.further_informtion
```

I want it to be sorted by it's IP adress, which I found as

```
sorted(list_of_ips, key=lambda ip: long(''.join(["%02X" % long(i) for i in ip.split('.')]), 16))
```

from [How to sort IP addresses stored in dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545023/how-to-sort-ip-addresses-stored-in-dictionary-in-python)

I have trouble transfering it though. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the doc:

***key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element. The default value is None.***

so the actual argument to your above lambda function you provided as the key is the instances of your 'myClass', so in order to sort your class instances by ip, you should write sth like:

```
key=lambda my_instace: long(''.join(["%02X" % long(i) for i in my_instance.ip.split('.')]), 16))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[instance_of_myClass, instance_of_myClass, instance_of_myClass...].sort(lambda a, b: cmp(a.ip, b.ip))
```

Comment: This only works if `cmp` is defined in a reasonable way for the `ip` objects -- which based on string mangling above, I doubt is the case ... Also, I believe this comparison usage is deprecated in favor of `key` as used in the other answer.