# Sorting IPv4 and IPv6 address in a Database

Tags: python, django

I have a field for storing IP addresses and I'm using this code to convert an IPv4 address to an integer so I can save a sortable version of the address in a separate bigint field to achieve more natural sorting (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545023/how-to-sort-ip-addresses-stored-in-dictionary-in-python)):

```
octets = ip.split('.')
return (int(octets[0]) * 256**3) + (int(octets[1]) * 256**2) + (int(octets[2]) * 256) + (int(octets[3]))
```

How can I do something similar with IPv6 addresses which is too big for a bigint field?

And is there a simple way to do the integer conversion for IPv6? Python3 seems to provide this with the "ipaddress" module, but I'm using 2.7. I want to support the various ways of leaving zero's out of the address.

**Update**: I'm using Django 1.5

Comment: Have you tried `NUMERIC(39)` for PostgreSQL 9.1+ and MySQL 5.5+? The 128-bit range contains numbers with up to 39 digits (`log10(2**128 - 1) = 38.53`). It would good if you had provided your db engine.

Comment: @kroolik, I'm using MySQL via Django, but I don't want to be tied to a DBMS if possible. Django doesn't look like it has a Numeric field type.

Comment: Try `DecimalField(max_digits=39)`. It maps into `NUMERIC(max_digits, decimal_places)`. The number of digits is 39, because you would want to store unsigned `2**128`, which fits into 129-bit signed number. And `log10(2**129) = 38.83`.

Comment: @kroolik, thanks... not sure how I missed that. And I found another answer which used "socket" and "struct" to convert IPv6 to an integer, so its all sorted out now.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this code to convert the IPs to integers:

```
import struct, socket

try:
    return struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip))[0]
except socket.error:
    try:
        hi, lo = struct.unpack('!QQ', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip))
        return (hi << 64) | lo
    except socket.error:
        return 0
```

Using a DecimalField worked, as recommended by kroolik

Answer (score -1):

I believe I'd split IPv4 addresses on ., and sort as a list.
Similarly for IPv6, I'd try splitting on :, and sorting them as a list too.

And wrapping this up as a class would probably be a good idea, in case the behavior needs to change someday.  That way, if it does change, the changes aren't scattered across your code.

Comment: I decided to use socket rather than just handling the address as a string once I saw what a IPv6 validation regex looks like. And I have it as a static method in a class, I just didn't bother to show that part of the code here. Thanks though.

Comment: You can't simply use a list for ipv6 addresses and expect them to sort right.  The format for ipv6 allows the user to use :: once in place of 1 or more groups of zeros.  If the address is not normalized, that can occur in more than one place for the same ipv6 address.

Comment: So why does that make it "not sort right"?  There are many definitions of <, = and >. Some are more intuitive than others, but most can be used for deduplication or whatever.

EG, I wrote a program that would sort files by their sizes, inodenumber, devicenumber, hash of a prefix, hash of the entire file, and finally, the entire file - but only if necessary, for speed.  It's not an intuitive sort, but it was very effective for my purpose.