# How can I get the list sorted out according to the IP address?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding:utf8 -*-

import sys
import fileinput
import socket

hostlist= ['www.yahoo.com','www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com', 'www.cnn.com', 'www.thetimes.com']

for line in hostlist:
    for hostnames in line.split():
        try:
            socket.gethostbyname(hostnames)
        except Exception as invalid_hostnames:
            print ('Invalid hostname address = ') + hostnames
        else:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostnames)
            print (ip.ljust(30,' ')) + '' + (hostnames.ljust(30,' '))
```

the output comes as below

```
46.228.47.115                 www.yahoo.com                 
123.176.0.162                 www.google.com                
179.60.192.36                 www.facebook.com              
185.31.17.73                  www.cnn.com                   
54.229.184.19                 www.thetimes.com
```

Would it be possible to get the output sorted out according to the resolved IP address?

Comment: Seems to have been solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545088/6004486)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import socket

results = []

with open('hostnames_list.txt') as f:
    for hostname in f:
        try:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname.strip())
        except socket.gaierror:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname('.'.join(hostname.strip().split('.')[1:]))
        results.append((ip, hostname.strip()))

for (ip, hostname) in sorted(results, key=lambda item: socket.inet_aton(item[0])):
    print (ip.ljust(30,' ')) + '' + (hostname.ljust(30,' '))
```

> **Note:** See that I'm using [socket.inet_aton](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton) to convert an IPv4
>   address from dotted-quad string format (for example, ‘123.45.67.89’)
>   to 32-bit packed binary format, as a string four characters in length. This way, you'll have them sorted correctly.

E.g.

```
data = [
        ('31.13.73.36', 'google.com'),
        ('31.13.72.35', 'foo.bar'),
        ('31.13.72.36', 'somedomain.com')
]
print sorted(data, key=lambda item: socket.inet_aton(item[0]))
```

Will output:

```
[
    ('31.13.72.35', 'foo.bar'),
    ('31.13.72.36', 'somedomain.com'),
    ('31.13.73.36', 'google.com')
]
```

Comment: your method above works perfectly :) is it possible to pass a hostname list and get the output the same ?

Comment: @iqzer0, it's actually getting the hostname list: **hostlist**. Do you want it to be a function or what?

Comment: i want to pass a hostname list file , eg: hostlist.txt
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.facebook.com

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Aren't you only sorting by the first octet? What if they're the same?

Comment: i have a huge list of hostnames in a file, i want to sort it according to all the octets
172.168.0.1
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.3

it would be great if you could help me out :)

Comment: @iqzer0 I'm fixing it, give me a second

Comment: okay :) this is great, i was trying to use this method [ http://wadofstuff.blogspot.com/2007/02/sorting-ip-addresses-in-python.html ] 
but since am noob, i couldn't get it working :(

Comment: i am getting the error below when i pass the hostnames_list.txt 

socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: @iqzer0 [`sorted(list_of_ips, key=lambda ip: long(''.join(["%02X" % long(i) for i in ip.split('.')]), 16))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545088/6004486) (I don't want to post it as my own answer since it's not)

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. solution is perfect, but when i give long a hostname with subdomain it goes crazy..

Comment: use the list i have in that paste, it doesn't work with it

Comment: @iqzer0 www.booking.qatarairways.com/ seems to be down

Comment: @jDo  yes, some of the host's are down in the list i want to provide.

Comment: @iqzer0 Then just add a `try: except:` around the line of code that attempts to fetch the hostname. You won't get that particular IP but at least the script will continue despite errors

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. you made my day :D this is just perfect... Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly with the list i have.. i just gave it a run, it works :D

Comment: @iqzer0 that's great! Have a nice weekend pal.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. could you be kind enough to remove those hosts from results :) thanks a lot mate!!

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Aren't you still sorting only by the first octet?!

Comment: @jDo `key=lambda item: socket.inet_aton(item[0])` sorts by all the octets. item is (ip, hostname) so **item[0]** is the **ip**, which is evaluated by socket.inet_aton. See the last example of my answer.

Comment: @jDo i checked and it seems to be sorting all the octets :D

Comment: @iqzer0 and Andrés Pérez-Albela H, you're right! My bad! It seems to work now :) `item[0]` --> `item` made it work (because I only tried with a list of IPs, not a list of IP+domain name tuples

Answer (score 1):

You should first generate a list of entries in the form `(hostname, ip)` for example. After generating that list, iterate over it with `sorted()` and print out the contents.

For example, instead of the print, make a list:

```
 result = []
```

And append your entries to that list instead of printing them out:

```
result.append((hostname, ip))
```

Then, after processing all items, print them out sorted:

```
for hostname, ip in sorted(result, key=lambda v: v[1]):
    print (ip.ljust(30,' ')) + '' + (hostnames.ljust(30,' '))
```