# Sorting IP Addresses in a Python Script

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to sort IP Addresses which I'm reading into a python script and printing out. The code that I've drafted up reads and prints the contents of a file (see example)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('file.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
f.close()
```

My issue is how do I take that importing of IP Addresses and sort them correctly? At the command line I would normally pass the file through a simple sort command (sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 ). But how can I get python to sort the IPs it's reading from the file so the output is sorted correctly, taking into consideration the 0-255 numbering schema for each octet of an IP?

Thanks,

Comment: So you want the IP's to be sorted in this way - `0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.1, --------.255.255` ? .

Comment: That is correct. I want all the IPs to end up being sorted in that fashion.  Obviously they will all be different addresses (think random IP addresses), but I want them all in a sorted format such as:  10.11.12.13 -> 128.2.4.6 -> 192.0.3.4 -> 208.11.45.8... and so on.

Comment: Then this answer will solve your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545088/3225001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use any external software and want a compact solution, you can always supply a lambda function as sort key.

```
with open("ip.txt", "r") as infile:
    iplist = sorted([i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()], key = lambda x: int(''.join((lambda a:lambda v:a(a,v))(lambda s,x: x if len(x) == 3 else s(s, '0'+x))(i) for i in x.split('.'))))
```

This assumes normal IPv4s in ip.txt separated by a line break.

The resulting `iplist` ist a sorted list with the IPs. You can also output them to file like this:

```
with open("ip.txt", "r") as infile:
    iplist = sorted([i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()], key = lambda x: int(''.join((lambda a:lambda v:a(a,v))(lambda s,x: x if len(x) == 3 else s(s, '0'+x))(i) for i in x.split('.'))))

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(i for i in iplist))
```

The output file could be the same as the input or a different file.

Comment: This works great, but how can you remove all the bracketing and quotes and force the output to be a single column with just the IP addresses by themselves?  What I'm getting is ['5.6.240.180', '9.2.35.35', '16.166.188.35'] as an example.

Comment: @Alby I edited the code with explanations on how to write the result to file again.

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense. Please help my stackexchange score with an up arrow click if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built-in [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ipaddress

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   ips = sorted(ipaddress.ip_address(line.strip()) for line in f)
   print('\n'.join(map(str, ips)))
```

If you're using an older Python version (before 3.3), you may need [my backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress). Also note that this code employs the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for file I/O, [as this handles errors correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2738365/35070).

With `ipaddress`, the IP addresses are actually tested for validity. Also, the code can correctly handle IPv6 addresses (i.e. `::1.2.3.4 > 000::12a0`) as well as esoteric representations such as `2130706433`, although you cannot mix IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Alternatively, you can use a [natural sort algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm). This will not verify the addresses and may be incorrect, but works as long as you input is always IPv4 addresses in the form `1.2.3.4`.